# Compare two lists and remove first matching duplicate from list2

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists and I'm trying to remove the first duplicate item from list2.

```
list1 =["cat"]
list2 = ["cat","dog","elephant","cat"]
```

expected output

```
list2 = ["dog","elephant","cat"]
```

I've tried using sets, but that removes ALL duplicates. I just want to remove the first duplicate found in the second list.

```
new_list = list(set(list2) - set(list1))
```

Comment: ```list2.pop(list2.index(list1[0]))```? Or ```list2.remove(list1[0])```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> list1 = ["cat"]
>>> list2 = ["cat", "dog", "elephant", "cat"]
>>> list2.remove(next(x for x in list1 if x in list2))
>>> list2
['dog', 'elephant', 'cat']
```

We use a list comprehension to find the common elements between the two lists, then just find and remove the first one.

Comment: Do `set`s guarantee their elements to be in a particular order when made into a list?

Comment: @Scott Whoops, you're absolutely right. This doesn't work. I'll edit the answer.